# How would I call my function before the form actually submits?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to get this code to work for the past few days. I need to call a function before the form is submitted to check if the class for each of the variables is the same thing. Here is my [code](https://codepen.io/yameen101/pen/eYdeEpp). Please let me know and I thank you in advance.

`code`

Comment: Please post your code in the question and tell us what specifically isn't working and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error at the end of **line 67** of [your code snippet](https://codepen.io/yameen101/pen/eYdeEpp).

```
character.classList.item(0) == 'valid'.) {
```

You should not have a `.` after `'valid'`.

It's also best practice to use `element.addEventListener()` rather than setting `.onkeyup` or `.onsubmit` directly.

Here's a code sample that works.

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("password1");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");
var character = document.getElementById("character");

// When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
myInput.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
});

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
myInput.addEventListener("blur", function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
});

// When the user starts to type something inside the password field
myInput.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  // Validate lowercase letters
  var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
  if (myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate capital letters
  var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
  if (myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
    capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    capital.classList.remove("valid");
    capital.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  // Validate numbers
  var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
  if (myInput.value.match(numbers)) {
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate length
  if (myInput.value.length >= 8) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  var special = /[!@#$%^&*]/g;
  if (myInput.value.match(special)) {
    character.classList.remove("invalid");
    character.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    character.classList.remove("valid");
    character.classList.add("invalid");
  }
});

document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  if (letter.classList.item(0) == 'valid' && capital.classList.item(0) == 'valid' && number.classList.item(0) == 'valid' && length.classList.item(0) == 'valid' && character.classList.item(0) == 'valid') {
    alert("Validation passed");
  } else {
    alert("Validation failed");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  color: rgb(228, 185, 107);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5vw;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}


/* Style all input fields */

input {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(228, 185, 107);
  color: black;
  font-size: 3vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  border: 0.5vw solid rgb(134, 134, 134);
  cursor: auto;
}

#submit {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(228, 185, 107);
  border: 0.5vw solid rgb(228, 185, 107);
}

#username1 {
  margin-left: 2vw;
}


/* Style the submit button */

form {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3vw;
}


/* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */

#message {
  display: none;
  color: rgb(228, 185, 107);
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}


/* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */

.valid {
  color: rgb(0, 172, 0);
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -5vw;
}


/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */

.invalid {
  color: rgb(255, 72, 72);
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.message h1 {
  margin-left: 2vw;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: left;
  padding: -1vw;
}

#message h1 {
  position: absolute;
}

#letter {
  top: 2vw;
}

#capital {
  top: 2vw;
  right: 2vw;
}

#character {
  top: 5vw;
  right: 2vw;
}

#number {
  top: 3vw;
  left: 35vw;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
  </script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Sign Up</h1>

  <form method="POST" id="myform" name="form" action="signup.php">
    <input type="text" id="name1" name="name1" required="" placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" id="username1" name="username1" required placeholder="Username">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="password" id="password1" placeholder="Password" name="password1" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </form>

  <div id="message" class="message">
    <h2>Password <b>must</b> contain the following:</h2>
    <h1 id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</h1>
    <h1 id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</h1>
    <h1 id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></h1>
    <h1 id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></h1>
    <h1 id="character" class="invalid">Minimum <b>1 special character (!@#$%^&*)</b></h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note how the use of `e.preventDefault()` will stop the form submitting if validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, it was a typo:

```
document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener('submit', function(event){
if(letter.classList.item(0) != 'valid' || capital.classList.item(0) != 'valid' || number.classList.item(0) != 'valid' || length.classList.item(0) != 'valid' || character.classList.item(0) != 'valid') {
  event.preventDefault;
  alert('Please fill in required characters in password field');
}
});
```